# Persistent invalid edits from the same user

Tags: discussion

In recent days I have got a good number of invalid edits in the review queue by user [Pabi](https://askubuntu.com/users/173631/pabi). In most cases the user simply inserts blanks lines, but other times it is the deletion of entire portions of the post.

Is there any procedure to deal with this kind of persistent delinquent behaviour?

Comment: If you can link to specific revisions I could comment more but I've just had a quick look at his recent edits and they seem *generally* okay.

Answer (score 3):

Just keep marking them as "invalid" or rollback the edits.

At some point someone will get angry and clubber him.

---

By the way: the 3 edits I saw on the frontpage showed not a lot wrong with his/her edits :)

Comment: I will certainly keep marking invalid edits, no matter from which user. What do you mean by "clubber him"?

Comment: You know. Take out a club and start swinging it. And then have it land on a head.